# Matrix multiplication with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization, multiplication

I need to vectorize the following loop

```
a=rand(m,n,k)
b=rand(n,k)
c=zeros(m,k)
for ik=1:k
  c(:,ik)=a(:,:,ik)*b(:,ik)
end
```

I couldn't find any matlab function for doing this and I think bsxfun @multiply does something different. Could you please help on doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `bsxfun` as follows (can't test this right now - let me know if this gives you trouble):

```
c = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, a, b), 2));
```

The `bsxfun` will expand the matrix b and then do element-by-element multiplication. The sum operation on the second dimension takes care of the "matrix multiplication" aspect.  It is possible that you need to expand `b` to have an explicit singleton first dimension:

```
c = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, a, reshape(b, 1, n, k)), 2));
```

Comment: this operation multiplies:  a(:,:,ik)*b   , but I need  a(:,:,ik)*b(:,ik)

Comment: @Parsa: the second version above produces identical output compared to your loop.

Comment: @horchler You're right. There was a mistake on my part. Thanks